# How to store a Sqlgeography type using ado.net?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, geospatial

Well, we have use ado.net to save db.

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Types;

DataRow dr = dt.Rows[0];
dr["gps_location"] = SqlGeography.Point(30.0, 122, 4326);  //ERROR
```

When it execute to the last sentence, it went wrong. The error is

> {"Type of value has a mismatch with column typeCouldn't store  in gps_location Column.  Expected type is SqlGeography."}

And this gps_location's Datatype in Sqlserver is geography

Comment: Did you import the correct *version* of ´Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography´ that matches your SQLServer?

Comment: @nvoigt Yes we have. The Sqlserver is 12.0.2000.8 and the Dll is also 12.0.2000.8

Comment: Perhaps a dumb question on my part, but the error message seems to indicate that something other than a SqlGeography is being returned by the Point method. What *is* being returned?

Comment: @BenThul Not a dumb question at all, but actually that's what we are pissed. According to the MSDN, SqlGeography.Point returns an instance of SqlGeography.  Here is the MSDN link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.types.sqlgeography.point.aspx